# Ghost Forms in C# APP

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a problem in WinForms with some Ghost Forms, the form has `this.Close()` and when I send the `close` command, it disappears but is still in memory. To properly close these forms I created this method:

```
public static void CloseAllForms()
        {
            //foreach (frmBase item in Application.OpenForms)
            //{
            //    if (!item.Name.Equals("frmVinheta") && !item.Name.Equals("frmPrincipal"))
            //    {
            //        item.Dispose();
            //        item.Close();                    

            //    }
            //}

            for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i > 1; i--)
            {
                Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms[i] as Form1;

                Application.OpenForms[i].Dispose();
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
                Application.OpenForms[1].RemoveOwnedForm(Application.OpenForms[i]);
            }

            GC.Collect();
        }
```

But, the frm doesn't close, he stays in the OpenForms List and memory all of my dispositives lose it's Owner, sending it's events to the ghost form.

Someone know other thing i can test here???

Answer (score 1):

Some other process may have a handle open on your application. Can you close it manually? If not, try `Form.Dispose()`. If you can, there is an issue with your form reference. Maybe you're trying to close the form from an external class accidentally? Check your code and make sure that `this` is referencing your form. If it is, stick a breakpoint on your `Form.Close()` or `Form.Dispose()` and see if it's actually getting executed. If it isn't, check higher up on your method to see if you've stopped execution. If it is, I'm not sure what the problem could be.

EDIT:

You need to set the form to null before the GarbageCollect. However, instead of a method to close all forms, maybe implement `using` statements? Like So:

```
using (var frm = new Form2())
{
  //Form2 instance exists here
}
//Form2 instance gets Closed and disposed properly here
```

Comment: Don't have handle of other process in the app, the form don't appear to me, he was closed visualy, but debugging i can see it in the OpenForms List. the `this.Close()` works to remove the form from my sight, but don't remove it. The App works fine, but when i make a keyboard stress test opening forms, closing forms, working in the forms, one or more message forms (This message still for 8 seconds and close forms) still open in memory happens.

Comment: Ah, Do you mean it's still using memory?

Comment: he still in memory, but not appears to me, he still in the list of active forms `Application.OpenForms`

Comment: @JonesVG So when you run `Form.Show()`, it doesn't come up? Are you creating a Form instance?

Comment: @JonesVG I'm confused. In your question you say the form doesn't close, but in your comment, you're saying it doesn't appear. Could you please explicitly state what's happening?

Comment: OK, i send the close command, the form desapear, but still in memory, still  in the `Application.OpenForms` and don't show again, don't disapear of memory, but still receiving all events of my dispositives.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems a bit confusing. I'm going to add comments to point it out:

```
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i > 1; i--)
        {
            // Here you are obtaining a reference to the form, but not using it
            Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms[i] as Form1;

            // Here you are trying to Dispose, but then Close (instead of the other way around
            // I'm not sure why you'd do this unless you don't have cleanup being done at time of close.
            Application.OpenForms[i].Dispose();
            Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
            // It looks like your first form is the owner of every other form in the collection.
            // If possible, you may want to rethink this for clarity's sake.
            Application.OpenForms[1].RemoveOwnedForm(Application.OpenForms[i]);
        }
```

I assume you are wanting to `Close`, then `Dispose`, the form. It may be possible to do this:

```
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i > 1; i--)
        {
            Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms[i] as Form1;

            f1.Close();
            f1.Dispose();
            Application.OpenForms[1].RemoveOwnedForm(f1);
        }
```

- Is there anything in the child forms that would prevent full closure? This can include open threads, subscribed events (they can be weird sometimes), a `Cancel = True` call, `this.Hide()`, or anything like that? If so, make sure you terminate threads, unsubscribe from any events that you manually subscribed to, and handle any other aspects that may cause your form to stay alive.
- If you are using the `Dispose` method, make sure to do complete object cleanup of anything you may have instantiated that can keep a form alive.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I have solved it with some flags and a method to point my dispositives to the current non ghost form. Thanks for your help friends, but all ghost forms are working now.